# How to return a count of values in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, count

I'm trying to return the number of values that are in each list, which are housed in a bigger list.

```
l = [(32, -59), (33, -58)], 
    [(33, -58), (28, 17), (27, 81)], 
    [(33, 28), (95, 49)], 
    [(76, 9), (33, 4)]
```

I have tried to use `(sum(x.count('value') for x in l))` but this just returns the count of a single value.

I'm hoping to return:

```
2,3,2,2
```

I'm not too fussed what format it's in. Although, I'll eventually convert it to a df:

```
    1  2  3  4
 0  2  3  2  2
```

Comment: `print( [len(i) for i in l] )`

Comment: print(map(len, l))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `len`function:

```
l = [[(32, -59), (33, -58)],
    [(33, -58), (28, 17), (27, 81)], 
    [(33, 28), (95, 49)], 
    [(76, 9), (33, 4)]]
for i in l:
    print(len(i))
```

output:

```
2
3
2
2
```

Answer (score 4):

you have a very simple solution using `len()` :

```
>>> l = [[(32, -59), (33, -58)], 
...     [(33, -58), (28, 17), (27, 81)], 
...     [(33, 28), (95, 49)], 
...     [(33, 28), (95, 78)]]
>>> lengths=[len(a) for a in l]
>>> lengths
[2, 3, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `len` to get the size of an array.

**Ex:**

```
l = [[(32, -59), (33, -58)], 
    [(33, -58), (28, 17), (27, 81)], 
    [(33, 28), (95, 49)], 
    [(76, 9), (33, 4)]]

print( [len(i) for i in l] )
```

**Output:**

```
[2, 3, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map :

```
l = [[(32, -59), (33, -58)],
    [(33, -58), (28, 17), (27, 81)],
    [(33, 28), (95, 49)],
    [(76, 9), (33, 4)]]


print(list(map(len,l)))
```

output:

```
[2, 3, 2, 2]
```